# what parameter of a,b,c,d makes $|az+b|=|cz+d|$ a line, not a line segment?

Tags: complex-numbers

the equation of a line in complex plane is $arg(\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1})=0$ with $z_1$ and $z_2$ as two points on the line. But how can you specify such a line, but not a segment that passes through $b$ and $d$ that are colinear with $z$ in such a form with magnitude only?

Comment: $\arg(\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1})$ is not an equation. $|az+b|=|cz+d|$ **is** an equation, usually of a circle, sometimes a straight line; when do you think it is a line segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$, you can write it as $$\begin{align}|a|\bigg|z+\frac{b}{a}\bigg|&=|c|\bigg|z+\frac{d}{c}\bigg|\\ \frac{|z+\frac{b}{a}|}{|z+\frac{d}{c}|}&=\bigg|\frac{c}{a}\bigg|=k\end{align}$$
So, $z$ will represent a straight line only if $k=1$ i.e. $|a|=|c|$, else it will be a circle. See [this](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/show-that-the-locus-of-points-such-that-the-ratio/) illustration.

Now, we have $$\bigg|z+\frac{b}{a}\bigg|=\bigg|z+\frac{d}{a}\bigg|$$
This represents the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining the points $-\frac{b}{a}$ and $-\frac{d}{a}$.

Comment: I think this is missing some absolute value signs; don't you also get a straight line if $a = -c$?

Comment: @DavidK, it is ratio of distances which will always be positive.

Comment: What is the shape of $|z+1|=|-z+1|$?

Comment: @DavidK, got it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @DavidK The shape you asked would be whole imaginary axis. i.e. a line

Comment: @davidK, so this would be a line that is perpendicular to the segment that joins -b/a and -d/a?